# Correct Usage Of External JavaScript in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I have created a javascript file in github

The code in the js file is as follows :

```
function youTube(a,b,c,d)
{
 return ("<iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+a+"' width='210'/><iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+b+"' width='210'/><iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+c+"' width='210'/><iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+d+"' width='210'/>");
}
```

I used rawgit.com to create a CDN link and put it in script source(src)
And in Blogger>>Edit HTML, at the appropriate place where I wanted it I put the code :

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/example/CTGod/1bc76937/youtubebar.js' type='text/javascript'>
var a="zK5zn44YzKA";
var b="3d21j6xOejU";
var c="U8gD0XiOOL4";
var d="cLnR-L6fNqs";
document.write(youTube(a,b,c,d));
</script>
```

When I did not use the code that I have right now put in an external js file and used it normally it worked. The code looked like the below :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var a="zK5zn44YzKA";
var b="3d21j6xOejU";
var c="U8gD0XiOOL4";
var d="cLnR-L6fNqs";
function youTube(a,b,c,d)
{
  return ("<iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+a+"' width='210'/><iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+b+"' width='210'/><iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+c+"' width='210'/><iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+d+"' width='210'/>");
}

document.write(youTube(a,b,c,d));
</script>
```

Now, I want to know why the code ,which when put in external js file doesn't work.
If I need to change my source of js file tell me where to upload and how to use it the best way.

Comment: Have you tried splitting 2 tags <script>? like: `<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/yashas123/CTGod/1bc76937/youtubebar.js' ></script> <script type='text/javascript'> var a="..."...</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a separate script tag to render external js file like the following

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/yashas123/CTGod/1bc76937/youtubebar.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var a="zK5zn44YzKA";
  var b="3d21j6xOejU";
  var c="U8gD0XiOOL4";
  var d="cLnR-L6fNqs";
  document.write(youTube(a,b,c,d));
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, it's halfway there. Now is to debug the external JS, only the first iframe code : `<iframe allowfullscreen='1' frameborder='0' height='140' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+a+"' width='210'/>` works. Other iframe codes not working and the the footers and others texts below the code part is not loading anymore. Any fix?

Comment: This happend because of using documet.write try to use innerHTML with a div Id instead.

Comment: Ok...I'll try it out and tell the results tomorrow since it's already nearly 12AM IST here. Thanks :D

Comment: I need help, how to pass on the values of a,b,c,d while I am using innerHTML and div id?

Comment: What I did was put the iframes in `<p id='yT'> ......</p>` and used  `document.getElementById("yT").innerHTML;` by putting it in a function.

Comment: Ok done ... I put the function in js and others(div and var+function call) in blogger>>edit HTML wherever I wanted it to be and it worked thanks :D